# Segmentation fault in matrix multiplication C++

Tags: c++, matrix

I'm trying to make a function that receives as parameter two matrixes and returns the multiplication of both. But when I try to test it, it returns a segmentation fault, can anyone tell me why? And help me to fix it?

This is my function code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

vector<vector<double> > MMultiplication(vector<vector<double> > a, vector<vector<double> > b) {

    int a_columns = a[0].size();
    int a_rows = a.size();
    int b_columns = b[0].size();
    int b_rows = b.size();


    < vector<vector<double> > result;
    result.resize(a_columns);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
        //Grow Columns by b_rows
        result[i].resize(b_rows);
    }

    for (int p = 0; p < a_rows; p++) {
        for (int q = 0; q < b_columns; q++) {
            result[p][q] = 0;
        }
    }

    if (a_columns != b_rows) {
        cout << "Error: The number of columns of the first matrix needs to be equal to the number of rows of the second matrix" << endl;
        return result;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a_rows; i++) { //i iterate a rows
        for (int j = 0; j = b_columns; j++) //j iterates b columns
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < a_columns; k++) { //k goes back to a and iterates its columns
                result[i][j] += a[i][k] * b[k][j]; //sums all multiplications into result[i][j]
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

And this is the main i'm using to test my function:

```
int main ()
{
  vector < vector < double >>a;
  int m = 4, n = 2;
  //Grow rows by m
  a.resize (m);
  for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i)
    {
      //Grow Columns by n
      a[i].resize (n);
    }
  a[0] =
  {
  1, 0};
  a[1] =
  {
  1, 1};
  a[2] =
  {
  1, 2};
  a[3] =
  {
  1, 3};
  cout << a.size () << endl;
  cout << a[0].size () << endl;

  vector < vector < double >>b;
  int o = 2, p = 4;

  b.resize (o);
  for (int i = 0; i < o; i++)
    {
      b[i].resize (p);
    }
  b[0] =
  {
  1, 2, 3, 4};
  b[1] =
  {
  1, 3, 5, 7};

  vector < vector < double >>result = MMultiplication (a, b);
  cout << result.size () << endl;
  cout << result[0].size () << endl;

  /* for(int k = 0; k < result.size(); k++) {
     for(int q = 0; q < result[0].size(); q++)
     cout << result[k][q] << endl;
     } */

}
```

Also, it's important to point out that the function, so far, is returning a matrix of zeros if it's impossible to multiply a and b.

Thank you.

Comment: try running your code from a debugger to help identify where (and why) the problem occurs.

Comment: As mentioned above, you need to debug your code and use backtrace command to identify the root case(segmentation fault means you are trying to access a memory that was not previously allocated hence you don't have access.)

Comment: Since it seems your code is using `std::vector` and you don't seem to be using pointers anywhere, the most probable reason for your error is that you're going out-of-bounds when accessing your vector elements.  Instead of using `[ ]` to access your elements, use the `at()` function.  If you're going out-of-bounds, you will get an `out_of_range` exception thrown instead of a segmentation fault.

Comment: The code you show will not build. When creating a [mcve] to show us, it's important that it doesn't contain any unrelated errors as that distracts from the actual problem you have. It's also important that it really replicates the problem you have. Also please take some time to read about [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: If I'm reading correctly, the vector `result` has size `a_columns`, but then you iterate over it up to `a_rows`?  That doesn't seem right.

Comment: Look carefully at how your code declare, resize and then initialize `result`. Which, BTW, could be done in a single line of code.

Comment: Also note that the first two loops in the function can be replaced by a simple initialization: `std::vector<std::vector<double>> result(a_columns, std::vector<double>(b_rows));` Incidentally, that could possibly solve your problem as well, considering your zeroing loop.

Comment: First, stop using extraneous variables such as `b_rows` and others that supposedly hold the number of entries in your vectors.  Using these variables just makes it easier to make mistakes.  Use the vector's `size()` function -- it is never wrong.  Second, initialize your vectors in the vector constructor.  Instead, you're writing error-prone `for` loops to initialize your vectors (with the added danger of using those extraneous variables mentioned earlier).

Comment: For example `<vector<vector<double>> result;` when you could have done this: ` `<vector<vector<double>> result(a[0].size(), vector<double>(b.size()));`  -- There are no `for` loops -- everything is initialized on construction.